# How to copy Azure storage account contents (tables, queues, blobs) to other storage account

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-durable-functions

I'm using Azure Durable Functions and I want to make a copy of the "production data" storage account to another storage account, to test out some things (such as data migration strategies, performance and other issues).

For that, I was hoping to find the easiest and most out of the box way, to just copy the full contents of an Azure Storage Account to another Storage Account.

Is there something out there? Or maybe a PowerShell script that can perform this?

(replication only works for blob objects)

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage accounts are made up of 4 different types of storage: blobs, fileshares, queues and tables.  Different methods and/or strategies will be required to copy each type to a new storage account.

There are many tools you could use to automate the process including the Az PowerShell module, the az cli and the Azure REST API.  Not all tools provide methods for working with all 4 types of storage.

First you will need to create a new storage account to copy your data to.  Be aware that account names are globally unique not just unique within your tenant, are limited to 24 characters in length and can only be made up of lowercase letters and numbers.  You could use the `New-AzStorageAccount` PowerShell cmdlet to create the new account.

###### Blobs

Blob storage is made up of containers that hold blobs in a flat file structure.  You will need to recreate each container from your source account, this could be done using the PowerShell cmdlet `New-AzStorageContainer`.  Once the containers have been created you can use `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy` to copy the blobs from the container in your source account to the container in your new account.

###### Fileshares

The storage account can contain multiple fileshares each containing a nested folder structure of varying depth.  You can create a new file share in your destination account using `New-AzStorageShare`.  Once you've recreated your fileshares you'll need to recurse through the folder structure in each share to get all the files.  You can then use `New-AzStorageDirectory` to recreate the folder structure and `Start-AzStorageFileCopy` to copy the files into the new fileshare.

###### Queues

As queues use a publisher subscriber model and the data is transient it may be easiest to recreate the queue and use a variation on the method your current publisher uses to populate the new queue with data.  You can use `New-AzStorageQueue` to create the new queue.  Alternatively you could create the new queue and repoint the publisher to it and only repoint the subscripers once the old queue is drained.  For your use case the first approach may be more suitable.

###### Tables

The storage account can contain multiple tables each containing multiple rows of data.  You can use `New-AzStorageTable` to recreate the tables but this will not copy over the data they contain.  Unfortunately there isn't a cmdlet in the Az module to do this but the [AzTable module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzTable/2.0.2) contains the `Get-AzTableRow` and `Add-AzTableRow` cmdlets which should allow you to copy the rows to the new table.

###### Summary

In practice implementing all this will require quite a lengthy script which will only grow if you need the process to handle large volumes of data and handle errors to ensure an accurate copy.  I've developed a script that handles blobs and fileshares which was sufficiently robust and quick enough for the hobby project I needed it for.  However, it took several hours to copy around 10 accounts the largest of which contained less than 1Gb of data so probably won't scale well to a commercial environment.  The script can be found [here](https://github.com/NickGraham101/gandt-devops/blob/main/PSScripts/Copy-AzStorageAccount.ps1) if you wish to use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you can try azcopy functionality, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy):

```
azcopy copy 'https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-07-04T05:30:08Z&st=2019-07-03T21:30:08Z&spr=https&sig=CAfhgnc9gdGktvB=ska7bAiqIddM845yiyFwdMH481QA8%3D' 'https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer' --recursive
```

The example above copies the whole container from one account to another.

Comment: Is there any advantage to azcopy over the az cli (there is `az storage copy` subcommand) or the powershell az module?

Comment: It should not be, down the line they should use the same API. az cli Is more generic, while azcopy is just a tool composed for copy tasks.